# Android - Animate View to Wrap Screen

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I'm trying to make a View (in this case an ImageView) slide off one side of the screen and simultaneously reappear on the other. However, most of the search results I have found include Samsungs news about launching devices with wraparound screens for 2014, or this same task on other devices (such as [Make Image Wrap Around Screen Edge? - iPhone Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396286/make-image-wrap-around-screen-edge-iphone-obj-c)). Is this currently not possible in Android?

I've tried doing this with two animations on the same view, but I haven't had much success. Chaining the animations resulted in only the latter animation being performed, and performing them simultaneously caused them to negate each other. I have also looked into the various Interpolators, but I haven't achieved this effect. Any suggestions?